# How to determine the name of the sources.list entry for a specific package from packages.debian.org?

Tags: debian, apt

While trying to compile a software, `apt-get` threw an error saying it couldn't locate the package `libpyside-dev`. I searched that package on the net and it's found on https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpyside-dev. I don't know what repository I should add to `/etc/apt/sources.list` in order  to be able to install this package via `apt-get`.

Where is the sources.list entry written on that page?

## Edit

1. My `apt-cache policy` output is [here](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/57add3d75e7788617ef758fe98a2a6fa).
2. My Debian version (`cat /etc/debian_version`) is: `buster/sid`
3. Adding `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free` seems to solve the issue (along with other problematic packages) but I'm not sure if this is the correct way or not.

Comment: IF one of your configured repos can see it, `apt-cache madison packagename` should tell you what version(s) are available, and what URL(s) they come from.

Comment: Adding Sid is the correct thing to do, but you need to pin the repositories too (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `sources.list` entry for the package because it’s hosted in the default repositories in Debian. You should be able to run

```
sudo apt install libpyside-dev
```

and get the appropriate version for your distribution.

If you’re using Buster, you won’t be able to install `libpyside-dev` currently unless you also add `unstable` to your repositories, because the package was removed from Buster ([Qt4 is being removed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784512)); see [the Debian wiki for details](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting). In particular, you should pin your repositories so that packages from Buster are given priority over packages from Sid; add the following to `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 800
```

Comment: I removed the `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free` line from my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uninstalled that package, run `apt-get update` to be sure that I'm back to square one. Now I can not install the package (getting the same error) as expected. Editing `/etc/apt/preferences` as you stated did not help solving the problem. Changing the line `deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free` to `deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free` solved the problem. Your answer contains causuality so it has to be accepted. Thanks

Comment: No, no, no, you need to *add* the unstable repository (also known as Sid), not replace testing by unstable. Pinning becomes relevant when you have both repositories configured.

Comment: Okay, now it worked as you'd expected. Thank you again!